# Are Bi-photons and Fock States (with $N=2$) the same?

Tags: photons, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, coherent-states

I've been researching about quantum states of light, and I came across with both terms. For what I understand of both, I think they are the same (entangled individual photons with same position and frequency). Am I right?

Also, I'd like to ask if Fock states can be understood as an extreme squeeze of a coherent state where the uncertainty of the amplitude (or the number of photons) is zero (but this may imply an infinite uncertainty in the phase, which I don't know if makes any sense).

Comment: I'd suggest you ask one question per question. It seems quite useless to answer the second part of your question, as it is not even referenced in the title.  No-one will be able to find it when looking for the same question.  (In any case, the answer to the 2nd question is "No.")

Answer (score 1):

The Fock states are states with a well-defined number of particles (photons). This number can range from zero (the vacuum state) to an arbitrary large number. However, the notion of a Fock state does not make any reference any other degrees of freedom of the photons, other than the particle-number degree of freedom. In those cases where other degrees of freedom are included, those degrees of freedom would be the same for all particles in the Fock state.

A bi-photon is any state the contains exactly two photons. Since one of the Fock states has exactly two photon, one can say that this particular Fock state is a bi-photon state. However, one usually encounter bi-photon states when the states also have particular properties associated with their other degrees of freedom.

Often bi-photon states are used to describe bi-partite entanglement. One can only have an entangled state if the state carries other degrees of freedom in addition to the particle-number degrees of freedom. For instance, the [Bell-states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state) are entangled bi-partite states

Comment: Particle number is not a degree of fredom of a photon, but of a photonic mode. An n=2 Fock state is a state of 2 photos which are identical in ALL of their degrees of freedom. It is not just some state with exactly 2 photons.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I added a sentence to address your concern. I don't think the issue justifies a down vote.

Comment: Fock states are not simply states with a fixed number of photons.  Fock states are states with a fixed number of photons, **all of which are in the same state**.  So it does very much make reference to all other degrees of freedom.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: No it doesn't. It depends on the context where you use it. Often in literature Fock states are mentioned without mentioning any of the other degrees of freedom. In fact, some introductory texts would develop the idea of Fock states from a very simple single degree of freedom potential well perspective, without any other degrees of freedom. The concept of Fock state is not restricted to quantum optics. Therefore, they may not involve photons at all.

Comment: Well, replace "photons" by "bosons".  And if you study a simple harmonic oscillator, there is only one mode to consider, to all bosons are in the same state. The only reason why other degrees of freedom are not referenced is because there are none.  Fock states are really states of bosonic modes (such as of a harmonic oscillator) rather than of bosons.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Well there you have it then; precisely what I'm trying to say. So what is your issue then?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, your second question is already answered and so I will only answer your first question, the title question, where you ask, Are Bi-photons and Fock States (with N=2) the same?

Biphotons are a quantum entangled state comprising of two photons.

Fock states (N=2) are quantum states that is an element of the Fock space with a well defined number of quanta.

The Fock state is an eigenstate of the number operator with an eigenvalue  n k i.

Now the difference is that a biphoton is made of two entangled particles, but there is a :

1. single photon Fock state, and (where the entangled photons are separated, and only one is in a Fock state)
2. two pieces of single photon Fock states |1⟩|1⟩, (two separately prepared photons)
3. and there is one piece of two photon Fock state |2⟩. (this is what you are referring to)

The difference is that in the second case, the photons are at two different times, and in the third case, the photons are simultaneous.

So the answer is no, the two are not the same, there are different cases of a Fock state (N=2).

Please see the single photon Fock case here:

https://www.iqst.ca/quantech/research/fock.php

Comment: Any reference for 2)?

Comment: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/ms/lightslides.pdf


https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236038468_Experimental_generation_of_multi-photon_Fock_states

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/two-single-photon-fock-states-vs-one-two-photon-fock-state.888688/

Comment: Why the downvote?